# How do I stop 2 divs from overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I want the the smaller div to be right below the bigger red div, but I can't figure it out. I thought that display block css would place the smaller div below the bigger div, but that does not seem to work.

I can't post an image.  Here is a link http://s1.postimg.org/pzgvqi8y7/Capture1.jpg

Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Select Ye Favorite</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/list.css'/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.imgareaselect-0.9.10/css/imgareaselect-default.css" />
        <!--jquery and jquery UI scripts here -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <!--js pdf stuff -->
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>    -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jjspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script> 
        <!-- photo selection scripts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.imgareaselect-0.9.10/scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js"></script>
        <!--my scripts-->
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/list.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='header'><h1 id='titleSite'>List Life</h1></div>
        <div id='list'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the css

```
![html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
/*
* {
    border: 2px solid black;
}*/
#header{
   /* z-index:1;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#ECF7C6;
    height:60px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:-20px;*/
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 98.75%;
    margin-top: -2%;
    margin-bottom:0.5%;
    margin-left:0.25%;
    margin-right:0.25%;
    height: 100px;

    border: 2px dashed black;
    background-color:#FC3F4D;
    border-radius:5px;
}
div{height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    position:relative;

}
div  #titleSite{
    position:relative;
    top:10%;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    border: 2px dashed white;
}][2]
```

Comment: Because of position: fixed; of your #header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its happens because of `position:fixed` of your `#header` If you do not want to change this just add the following css

```
#header{
  top:0px;
}
#list{ 
    margin-top:100px;(height of your header + gap between both divs)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
#titleSite{
    position:relative;
    top:10%;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    border: 2px dashed white;
}
#list{ position: relate; top:90px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you are trying to achieve since your css styles are not too straight forward. The issue is quite simple, your header div has a `fixed` position specified. Fix-positioned element are taken out of the document flow and are rendered relative to the browser window so the list div will be "pushed" forward because it is not aware of the header div

To fix the issue remove the following css declaration...

```
position: fixed;
```

from the header div

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry about the messy css. I'm pretty novice at web development. I put 'position: fixed;' so that the header would stay in place as user scrolls down the page.  I guess I can't. :(

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id='header'><h1 id='titleSite'>List Life</h1></div>
<div id='list'></div>
```

**CSS**

add this

```
#list{ 
    margin-top:60px;
}
```

if you dont want to change your `#header` position `fixed`